# What's a natural way to say "If I can do it so can you!"?

Tags: translation, particles, idioms, proverbs

I would translate it as

> わたしが出来るとあなたも出来るよ！

Could someone help explain what a more natural translation would be, or even better if there's a saying or a common idiom to express the same idea?

P.s. is would be わたしが, not は, in this situation right?

Thank you

Comment: I would say 私にはできれば、あなたにもできるよ！

Comment: 「私に**は**できれば、」の「は」はないほうがいいです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say:

> 私にできるなら、あなたにもできるよ。

Answer (score 3):

> わたしが出来るとあなたも出来るよ！

Verb+と doesn't work, it sounds like the other person has to wait until after you've done it.

How about:

> わたし（みたいなひと）が出来るならあなたも出来るよ！

If (someone like me) can do it, so can you!

Or for example

> こっちでもできるならそっちも楽勝【らくしょう】だろうよ

Comment: Ohhhhhh, with this one answer I understand と now...

Answer (score -1):

俺様がやれるから、お前がたぶんやれないだろうがやって見れ！
...笑

Comment: Unless you are imitating some dialect, it is やって見ろ.